# Call asynchronous function inside constructor

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, constructor

I have a widget where an attribute is obtained through a query on a database. So this function has to be marked as asynchronous, but i can't call it inside a constructor. Does someone know how to solve this ?

```
class PositionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
   final String streetName;
   String date;
   List<Map> notification;
   final VoidCallback onDelete;

  PositionWidget({Key key, this.streetName, this.date,this.notification, @required this.onDelete}): super(key: key){
    this.notification = await DBHelper.instance.getNotification(this.streetName);
  }
}


Future<List<Map>> getNotification(String street) async {
    Database db = await DBHelper.instance.database;
    var res = await db.query(table, columns: [columnNot], where: '${DBHelper.columnName} = ?', whereArgs: [street]);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I think you should use Future or Stream builder according to your get method from db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this inside the constructor of your `StatefulWidget`

You need to make your call inside the the `initState()` method of the `PositionWidgetState` (the `State` of your `PositionWidget`

```
class PositionWidgetState extends State<PositionWidget> {
  var res;

  @override
  void initState() {
    res = getNotification(widget.streetName);
  }
```

You'll probably need to a FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder to deal with the result

Comment: The `FutureBuilder` is a widget like any other widget. It's listening on a Future and give multiple states of it . See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html to get more info

Comment: What kind of widget should i return when the ConnectionState of snapshot is not "done"?

Comment: You can return a `CircularProgressIndicator` for example or any other Widget you want like a text `Text("loading")`, an empty `Container`...

Answer (score 2):

You can't have an `async` constructor. Use a `FutureBuilder` probably the best solution.

Alternatively, you can wait for the result like this:

```
 PositionWidget({Key key, this.streetName, this.date,this.notification, @required this.onDelete}): super(key: key){
    DBHelper.instance.getNotification(this.streetName)
      .then((result){
         notification = result;
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
initState() {
 myAsyncInit();
}

myAsyncInit() async {
 //do async stuff
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.